# OData - converting parameter entity set to LINQ

Tags: linq, odata

I have an OData URI that works as I want, passing a value for a parameter called gridsize and retrieving the data from Results.  This is the URI and it works fine:

```
http://<webservice>/MULTI_POINT_PARAMParameters(gridsize=0.1m)/Results
```

I am trying to get the above URI to work using LINQ.  I am using an MVC service reference to generate the proxy class.  So I tried this LINQ:

```
var query = (from x in context.MULTI_POINT_PARAMParameters
                where
                x.gridsize == 0.1M
                select x);
```

However the above LINQ generates this URI, which fails saying "segement not found":

```
http://<webservice>/MULTI_POINT_PARAMParameters()?$filter=gridsize eq 0.1M}
```

What I really want LINQ to generate is this, which I know works:

```
http://<webservice>/MULTI_POINT_PARAMParameters(gridsize=0.1m)/Results
```

How can I get LINQ to generate the URI I want?  I've looked at [Linq2rest](http://www.reimers.dk/tutorials/using-linq2rest) but could not see how it can help me if I want to explicitly code the LINQ terms myself, rather than have Linq2rest generate "hidden" terms I cannot see.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge if you want to add filter in OData you have to use "$filter".

if you want to use "MULTI_POINT_PARAMParameters(gridsize=0.1m)" then you might have to use dynamic generation of LINQ.

After dynamic generation your query might look something like this

```
var query = (from x in context.MULTI_POINT_PARAMParameters(gridsize=0.1m)                
            select x);
```

I am just trying to give you a direction to think.Lets see what others have opinion on your question.

Comment: Thanks you've put me on the right track. When I specify the full key terms (I'd omitted them to simplify my question) it generates the URI I want, (apart from the /Results part, but now I see that is a different question.